# setting up log4j for gmail, does not recognize System.setProperty("mail.smtps.port", "587")

Tags: smtp, log4j, gmail

I am trying to setup a smtpappender for log4j using gmail as the smtp host.

I have read that the port number needs to be 465 or 587 (depending on tls or ssl) and that log4j for some reason doesnt allow a different port to be set inside log4j.properties configuration file.

I have read that the best way of doing this would be to use System.setProperty which would change the default javaxmail port to gmail.

However when I try to set the System.property entries the the default port still remains as 25

System.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
System.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");

I was wondering if someone could help me out, I am open to suggestions, I just need to smtpAppender to work for gmail, dont really care how to get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom [`SMTPAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html) and specify it in the log4j config file. [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=gmailappender) learns me that there are at least two blog posts which describes how to do it: [here](http://marcelo-olivas.blogspot.com/2009/11/gmail-and-log4j-e-mail-appender-error.html) and [here](http://blog.iclutton.com/2008/08/gmail-log4j-appender.html).